How to know what percentage of createReadStream has run?
const watch = async (req, res, next) => {
  const videoId = req.params.id;
  if(videoId) {
    const videoPath = api+`/${videoId}.mp4`
    const stat = fs.statSync(videoPath);
    const fileSize = stat.size;
    const range = req.headers.range;

    if (range) {
      const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
      const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
      if(start === 0) {
        await handleAddView(videoId);
      }
      const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;
      const chunkSize = end - start + 1;
      const file = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
      const head = {
        'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
        'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
        'Content-Length': chunkSize,
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
      };

      res.writeHead(206, head);
      file.pipe(res);

    } else {
      const head = {
        'Content-Length': fileSize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
      };

      res.writeHead(200, head);
      fs.createReadStream(videoPath).pipe(res);
    }
  }

});


I has api watch video used "fs.createReadStream". I want to know percent of video, that client loaded.
I tried "file.on('data')" but it does not work as expected.

use readStream.bytesRead eg: file.bytesRead
